# RegEx with rgb()

Tags: javascript, regex, rgb

I just wrote the following regex to capture all sorts of whitespace errors amongst an `rgb()` declaration. Is their a more concise way to capture the same patterns?

```
/( |    )*r( |  )*g( |  )*b( |  )*\(( | )*[0-9]+( | )*,( |  )*[0-9]+( | )*,( |  )*[0-9]+( | )*,*( | )*\)( | )*;*( | )*/g
```

The above regex captures all of these declarations:

```
rgb(255, 240, 0);
rgb(0,0, 0)
rgb (  0,12,0)
r gb(12,24,26 ) ;
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `( |    )*` can be simplified to ` *`.

Comment: Use `\s` for whitespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex looks superfluous. I'd use something like this:

`r\s*g\s*b\s*\(\s*\d{1,3}\s*(?:,\s*\d{1,3}\s*){2}\)\s*;?`

Note how whitespaces can be matched via `\s*`, and digits via `\d`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1qeThz/2)

To limit entries from 0-255, the following adaption is needed:

`r\s*g\s*b\s*\(\s*(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\s*(?:,\s*(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\s*){2}\)\s*;?`

Note that `\d` represents the set of all the ten digits. In case a subset of those digits is needed, we need to use them in a character set manually without the `\d`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1qeThz/3)

Comment: Thanks CinCout. I'm going to go with a modified version of what you've suggested: `rgb\(\s*\d{1,3}\s*(?:,\s*\d{1,3}\s*){2}\)` As this captures everything I need. If I wanted to limit the number range to `255`, how might I do that leveraging the `d` flag you've raised?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to match all cases which do *not* pass, I would just use the following single pattern for the format you expect, containing no whitespaces:

```
rgb\([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)
```

If you additionally wanted to assert that the numbers are all in the range of 0 to 255 then we can modify the above to:

```
rgb\((1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\)
```

Code sample:

```js
var invalid1 = "rgb(255, 240, 0)";
var invalid2 = "rgb(0,0, 0)";
var invalid3 = "rgb (  0,12,0)";
var invalid4 = "r gb(12,24,26 )";

var valid = "rgb(10,20,30)";

console.log(/^rgb\([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)$/.test(invalid1));
console.log(/^rgb\([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)$/.test(invalid2));
console.log(/^rgb\([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)$/.test(invalid3));
console.log(/^rgb\([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)$/.test(invalid4));

console.log(/^rgb\([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)$/.test(valid));
```

Comment: FWIW, `[0-9]` can be `\d` in JavaScript's regex. Might also throw a few `\s*` (any amount of whitespace) in there around the numbers. :-)